# How to set playback quality youtube api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have 2 youtube players on my site. Everything works fine but I cannot set playback quality. What am I doing wrong?

```
var playerInfoList = [{
  id: 'player',
  height: '390',
  width: '640',
  videoId: 'jU1_0T79Lew',
  playerVars: {
    'autoplay': 1,
    'autohide': 1,
    'showinfo': 0,
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady
  }
}, {
  id: 'player1',
  height: '390',
  width: '640',
  videoId: 'u-OxxLMvOXg',
  playerVars: {
    'autoplay': 0,
    'autohide': 1,
    'showinfo': 0,
  }
}];

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  if (typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined')
  return;

  for (var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length; i++) {
    var curplayer = createPlayer(playerInfoList[i]);
  }
}

function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
  return new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
    height: playerInfo.height,
    width: playerInfo.width,
    videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
    playerVars: playerInfo.playerVars,
    events: playerInfo.events
  });
}


// The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  playerInfo.id.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080'); // Here we set the quality (yay!)
}
```

Comment: did you try getting the available quality levels using **player.getAvailableQualityLevels()** before setting the video quality ?

Comment: Is this line `playerInfo.id.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');` should be `event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');` ?

Comment: Thanks, working like this.

Answer (score 4):

## [Playback quality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality)

> `player.getPlaybackQuality():String`
>
> - This function retrieves the actual video quality of the current video. Possible return values are `highres`, `hd1080`, `hd720`, `large`, `medium` and `small`. *It will also return `undefined` if there is no current video*.
>
> `player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void`
>
> - This function sets the suggested video quality for the current video. The function causes the video to reload at its current position in the new quality. If the playback quality does change, it will only change for the video being played. Calling this function does not guarantee that the playback quality will actually change. However, if the playback quality does change, the [`onPlaybackQualityChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onPlaybackQualityChange) event will fire, and your code should respond to the event rather than the fact that it called the `setPlaybackQuality` function.
>
> When you suggest a playback quality for a video, the suggested quality will only be in effect for that video. You should select a playback quality that corresponds to the size of your video player. For example, if your page displays a 1280px by 720px video player, a `hd720` quality video will actually look better than an hd1080 quality video. We recommend calling the `getAvailableQualityLevels()` function to determine which quality levels are available for a video

## NOTE

> If you call the `setPlaybackQuality` function with a `suggestedQuality` level that is not available for the video, then the quality will be set to the next lowest level that is available. For example, if you request a quality level of `large`, and that is unavailable, then the playback quality will be set to `medium` (as long as that quality level is available).

Base on this tutorial : [How to Control YouTube's Video Player with JavaScript](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/08/how-to-control-youtubes-video-player-with-javascript/)

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
width: 600,
height: 400,
videoId: 'Xa0Q0J5tOP0',
playerVars: {
color: 'white',
playlist: 'taJ60kskkns,FG0fTKAqZ5g'
},
events: {
onReady: initialize
}
});
}
```

**Changing Video Quality**

```
$('#quality').on('change', function () {
player.setPlaybackQuality($(this).val());
});
```

Try setting your `playerInfo` to a global variable and follow the tutorial above to help you set up a embedded youtube video.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the quality is no longer supported. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#october-24,-2019

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2022:**

It looks like in 2019 Google [removed the ability](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#:%7E:text=the%20documentation%20has%20been%20updated%20to%20reflect%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20api%20no%20longer%20supports%20functions%20for%20setting%20or%20retrieving%20playback%20quality) to set video quality.